# Does direct private-to-private IP routing within a shared VPC go through NATs and is it necessarily faster than going through a public proxy?

Tags: routes, ip, amazon-vpc, vpc, aws-vpc

Assume we have two instances in two different regions under a shared VPC with no public IPs (i.e. within two private clusters). How exactly does routing from one instance to the other work, assuming private addresses used? Does it necessitate the use of NATs (which I always assumed were for internal to external communication).

Now, say, we added an external load balancer for public accessibility to the target internal node. Would routing from the same instance to the other via the public proxy necessarily be faster? Are there any benefits the former option entails besides attack-surface reduction and (possibly) bypassing authentication needed for public ingress.

Comment: *"two instances in two different regions under a shared VPC"*  I believe clarifcation is needed: a single VPC does not span regions.  For two instances to be in two regions, they would necessarily be on two different VPCs, and to communicate privately requires VPC peering.  A [shared VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-sharing.html) is a normal VPC except that for one or more subnets, you have given one or more other accounts permission to create resources in that VPC, on that subnet (and, by definition, within the VPC's same region).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. In other words, shared VPCs overarching multiple regions are in-fact VPC peering behind-the-scenes (on a regional basis in my example)? For example, Google Cloud's [Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc) documentation makes no mention of this.

Comment: This sounds like the kind of thing you wouldn't want to hang your hat on, even if you get the answers you like.